# How can I put this method in a fragment?

Tags: methods, fragment, nfc, onnewintent

I took this method from an activity. How can I add in a Fragment?

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    readFromIntent(intent);
    if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){
        myTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference to your fragment, so when `onNewIntent` is called you can call a Fragment's method